# Scala Map fold instead of find

Tags: scala, functional-programming

Trying to replace `find` in `Map` with `fold` with no success. 
I made simple example to not dive into details of my types. 
How to replace it with `fold`?

```
val s: Map[String, Int] = Map("1" -> 1, "2" -> 0, "3" -> 1)

s.find(_._2 == 0) match {
  case Some((_, 0)) => "F"
  case _ => "T"
}
```

Comment: What is this ? What are your trying to do ? What is supposed to be the expected output of whatever you want to do ? How to replace "what" with fold ?

Comment: if map has at least one 0 as a value, I should get "F", in other case - "T"

Comment: And why do you want to do it with `fold` ? as fold will keep on traversing the map even after fiinding the answer (finding a 0 and thus being "F").

Comment: Is this what you need? `s exists (_._2 == 0)` I'm not sure fold is necessary.

Comment: I know. At the real code i have different types. During code review I was requested to change it because of readability

Comment: @Tom it doesn't cover "if-else" case

Comment: @green-creeper it returns a boolean, so you can construct whatever if-else you please: `if (s exists(_._2 == 0)) "T" else "F"`

Comment: @Tom it's change find to exists, not to fold

Comment: @green-creeper perhaps you should discuss with your code reviewer why they insist on using fold, when simpler solutions exist.

Comment: @Tom I presume we don't have enough context to know why the code reviewers insist `fold` is appropriate here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although there indeed may be better solutions than a fold for your problem, this is the answer to your question:

```
val s: Map[String, Int] = Map("1" -> 1, "2" -> 0, "3" -> 1)

s.foldLeft("T") {
  case (_, (_, 0)) => "F"
  case (res, _) => res
}
```

The point is that you have to keep passing on the result gathered so far in the default case.

Comment: Thank you!
Could you please explain me why there is foldLeft("T") ?

I tried to do this and my approach keeps traversing and doesn't return correct answer

`s.foldLeft("") { case (a, (k, v)) =>`
`v match {`
`case 0 => "F"`
`case _ => "T"`
`}`
`}`

Comment: Your attempt ignores the result determined so far, which is `a` in your case. Yours is similar to something like `var res = ""; for ((key, value) <- s) res = if (value==0) "F" else "T"`. So if it finds a 0 in one iteration it ignores that in the next and overwrites the result and basically just returns T or F based on the very last element in the map. So mine starts with `"T"` and passes that on until it finds one 0, from which point both cases will return "F" (because `res` will be "F" from that point). Hope that helps! If not you should probably read a bit deeper into what folds actually do.